# How to render a template inside a "web/templates/folder/subfolder"

Tags: phoenix-framework

From my layout (`app.html.eex` file) I want to render a template that is inside a subfolder (2nd level folder) in my templates folder (sample structure):

```
/templates/layout
/templates/layout_module/header_footer/fad.html.eex
```

I have views for all 1st level folders (`layout, layout_module,...`).
I'm using:

```
<%= render FabricaASA.Layout_moduleView, "/header_footer/fad.html" %>
```

I've tried a few alternatives with no success.
What's the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the answer from Chris McCord (creator of PhoenixFramework) here: https://elixirforum.com/t/how-to-render-a-template-inside-a-web-templates-folder-subfolder/1404

In `web.ex` file add the `pattern` option:

```
use Phoenix.View, root: "web/templates", pattern: "**/*"
```

Then just use:

```
<%= render FabricaASA.Layout_moduleView, "header_footer/fad.html" %>
```